# Burnside's Lemma - Striped Flags

Tags: combinatorics

Given **q** distinct colours, how many striped flags are there having **n** stripes of equal width, so that stripes next to each other are coloured differently?

Does anyone know the solution to this this problem? Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need Burnside here? How many choices are there for the first stripe? How many for the second, third and so on?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to state the symmetries? As the question stands, there's no group to apply Burnside's lemma to.

Comment: It is likely the group is cyclic by looking at a flag as a cylinder.

Comment: I would say there are q(q-1)(q-1)... possibilities to create such a flag (for the first stripe you can choose any of the q colours, but the next stripe must not have the colour you chose before) and now you have to remove those flags which are the same. Now I am not quite sure how to determine the flags which are the same. I guess you need Burnside for that.

Comment: @Rokutaro No, wich flags are the same is part of the statement of the problem. Are two flags the same if they are a reflection in the vertical axis? If they have the same colors but in different order? If you don't provide statement of the problem, it's impossible obviously to know what the answer could be.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this

It may be a way

For first stripe you have q choices

For the second you have q-1

For the third you can use the colour used in the 1st stripe but you cannot use the one you used in the second

So for the third too it is q-1

And so on

It is **q(q-1)(q-1)(q-1)...**[n-1 times]

It is n-1 as you have put the number of choices of the first one as q, remaining n-1 stripes have q-1 possiblilities

We get answer as $q(q-1)^{(n-1)}$